# Hostapd error nl80211: Could not configure driver mode

Tags: wifi, hostapd

Hostapd keeps giving me this error:

> nl80211: Could not configure driver mode 
>   nl80211 driver initialization
>   failed. hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started

I'm on Debian 8. I googled for hours and can't find a fix that works with Jessie.

Comment: I found a solution in http://www.niwi.cz/clanky/it-poznamky/hostap-complete-wi-fi-ap-configuration-730.
Try it and post if you could get it solved. It worked for me. Good luck

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue on my raspberry-PI. I could not find any proper solution but I did come up with a slightly dirty way to solve the issue:

1. slightly modified solution from "adrianTNT" [here on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472794/hostapd-error-nl80211-could-not-configure-driver-mode#478097)

   ```
   airmon-ng check
   ```

   and the process I needed to kill was `wpa_supplicant` so

   ```
   killall wpa_supplicant
   ```
2. I had to run this command to successfully start hostapd

   ```
   hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
   ```

   instead of the more common way `service hostapd start` which always failed.

Answer (score 5):

This message appear also if hostapd is still running for some reason in the background. So try `sudo killall hostapd`.

Comment: For me, "service hostapd restart" did not work. This did the trick.

Comment: It indeed was `hostapd` in the background, thank you! Once terminated, all other instances worked well. Just in case, the error messages were (in order):
`nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured`
`nl80211: Could not configure driver mode`
`nl80211: deinit ifname=wlx0 disabled_11b_rates=0`
`nl80211 driver initialization failed.`
`wlx0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED`
`wlx0: AP-DISABLED`
`wlx0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING`
`hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlx0 wasn't started`